# Draw two textures to a new texture in opengl

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I basically have two textures, one base, and one overlay. I need two draw both of them to a new texture.

So, if texture 1 is:

```
AAAAA
BBBBB
CCCCC
```

and texture 2 is:

```
 B
 B
 A
```

then it should return:

```
ABAAA
BBBBB
CACCC
```

except it would be with actual textures, not letters.

(Note: the empty characters are transparency, which are ignored)

UPDATE 1:

I cannot use shaders, as this is in a modding environment, and I need to bind a texture to be drawn by an external renderer. Does that make sense?

UPDATE 2:

The alpha for the second image can be anything. 0.0 or transparent means do nothing with it and use the 1st image, otherwise use 2nd image

Comment: What you are looking for is blending https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending . Basically you first draw a quad with texture 1 and after that a quad with texture 2, where the color from texture 2 is weighted by the alpha value. So if the alpha value from texture 2 is 0 you will see texture 1 and if the alpha value is 1 than you see texture 2.

Comment: This is doable using multitexturing or shaders (but it won't create a single output texture). What kind of transparency is texture 2 using? Just **0.0** and **1.0**? _Can you explain why they need to be combined into a single texture versus both applied simultaneously?_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up an FBO with the resulting texture as attachment, and then mix the two input textures in the fragment shader. This is just an outline of the steps:

1. Create and allocate result texture.
2. Create and bind FBO (`glGenFramebuffers`, `glBindFramebuffer`).
3. Attach the result texture to the FBO.
4. Bind the two input textures to two different texture units.
5. Bind a program with a fragment shader that samples from two textures, and mixes them. The GLSL code could look something like this:

   ```
   in vec2 TexCoord;
   uniform sampler2D Texture1;
   uniform sampler2D Texture2;
   out FragColor;
   void main() {
       vec4 texVal1 = texture(Texture1, TexCoord);
       vec4 texVal2 = texture(Texture2, TexCoord);
       FragColor = mix(texVal2, texVal1, texVal2.a);
   }
   ```
6. Set up attributes, uniforms, etc.
7. Render a screen size quad.